# Boost, creating a thread that's creating a socket reader - Getting a compile error

Tags: c++, compiler-errors

I'm writing code for a gateway (aka router), using boost, C++, Codeblocks on a Linux device running Debian 7.1. I'm stuck with an annoying boost bind error and I simply cannot figure out what the problem is. I have been able to print out the MAC Header before I started creating threads

Here's a my code:

```
#include <errno.h>
#include <sys/ioctl.h>
#include <boost/thread.hpp>
#include <boost/function.hpp>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <linux/if_packet.h>
#include <linux/if_ether.h>
#include <linux/if_arp.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <features.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

using namespace std;

int CreateRawSocket(int protocol_to_sniff)
{
    int s;

    if((s = socket(AF_PACKET, SOCK_RAW, htons(protocol_to_sniff))) == -1)
    {
        perror("Error creating raw socket");
        exit(-1);
    }

    return s;
}

int BindRawSocketToInterface(char *device, int raw, int protocol)
{
    struct sockaddr_ll sll;
    struct ifreq ifr;

    bzero(&sll, sizeof(sll));
    bzero(&ifr, sizeof(ifr));

    strncpy((char *)ifr.ifr_name, device, IFNAMSIZ);
    if((ioctl(raw, SIOCGIFINDEX, &ifr)) == -1)
    {
        printf("Error getting interface index!\n");
        exit(-1);
    }

    sll.sll_family = AF_PACKET;
    sll.sll_ifindex = ifr.ifr_ifindex;
    sll.sll_protocol = htons(protocol);

    if((bind(raw, (struct sockaddr *)&sll, sizeof(sll))) == -1)
    {
        perror("Error binding raw socket to interface\n");
        exit(-1);
    }

    return 1;
}

int rawpacket_recv(int s, unsigned char *packet, int length)
{
    int to_recv = 0;

    to_recv = read(s, packet, length);
    if(to_recv == -1)
    {
        perror("Error receiving packet");
        exit(-1);
    }

    return to_recv;
}

int PrintPacketMACHdr(unsigned char *eth_packet)
{
    unsigned char *ethhead;
    int j;

    ethhead = eth_packet;

    printf("---Start of Ethernet header---");
    printf("\nDestination address:\n");
    for(j = 0; j < 6; j++)
    {
        printf("%02x:", *(ethhead+j)); //destination address (0 to 6 bit)
    }

    printf("\nSource address:\n");
    for(j = 6; j < 12; j++)
    {
        printf("%02x:", *(ethhead+j)); //source address
    }

    printf("\nEther protocol number:\n");
    for(j = 12; j < 14; j++)
    {
        printf("%02x", *(ethhead+j)); //protocol number
    }

    printf("\n---End of Ethernet header---\n");

    if(*(ethhead + 12) == 8 && *(ethhead + 13) == 0)
    {
        return 1; //IP packet
    }

    if(*(ethhead + 12) == 8 && *(ethhead + 13) == 6)
    {
        return 2; //ARP packet
    }

    return 0;
}

int CreateAndBindSocket(int protocol_to_sniff, int *socket, char *interface)
{
    int ethSocket = *socket; //eth1recv;

    ethSocket = CreateRawSocket(protocol_to_sniff);

    BindRawSocketToInterface(interface, ethSocket, ETH_P_ALL);

    return ethSocket;
}

void RecvThread(int *socket) //thread function for receiving packets
{
    int counter;
    unsigned char *eth_buffer;
    int eth_receiver;
    int eth_socket = *socket

    eth_buffer = (unsigned char *)malloc(ETH_P_ALL);
    eth_receiver = rawpacket_recv(eth_socket, eth_buffer, ETH_P_ALL);

    for(;;)
    {
        cout << "thread iteration " << ++counter << " Press Enter to stop" << endl;

        try
        {
            //Sleep and check for interrupt();
            //boost::this_thread::sleep(boost::posix_time::milliseconds(500));
            usleep(50000);
            PrintPacketMACHdr(eth_buffer);
        }
        catch(boost::thread_interrupted&)
        {
            cout << "Thread is stopped" << endl;
            return;
        }

    }
}

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    int eth0socket, eth1socket;

    char eth0[] = "eth0";
    char eth1[] = "eth1";

    eth0socket = CreateAndBindSocket(ETH_P_ALL, &eth0socket, eth0);
    eth1socket = CreateAndBindSocket(ETH_P_ALL, &eth1socket, eth1);

    boost::thread eth0recvthread(RecvThread, &eth0socket); //instantiate thread in main

    char ch;
    cin.get(ch);

    eth0recvthread.interrupt();
    eth0recvthread.join();

    return 0;
}
```

Right now I'm trying to create a thread that listens on one of the sockets and (for now) prints the MAC Header of the Ethernet frame. Later I will have to save the packet in some sort of array and then make another thread that handles the packets in this array. But as the headline says, I'm getting a boost error:

```
/home/thomas/Workspace/minisniffer/main.cpp||In function ‘void RecvThread(int)’:|
/home/thomas/Workspace/minisniffer/main.cpp|181|warning: variable ‘eth_receiver’ set but not used [-Wunused-but-set-variable]|
../../../../usr/local/boost_1_54_0/boost/bind/bind_template.hpp|20|  required from ‘boost::_bi::bind_t<R, F, L>::result_type boost::_bi::bind_t<R, F, L>::operator()() [with R = void; F = void (*)(int); L = boost::_bi::list1<boost::_bi::value<int*> >; boost::_bi::bind_t<R, F, L>::result_type = void]’|
../../../../usr/local/boost_1_54_0/boost/thread/detail/thread.hpp|117|  required from ‘void boost::detail::thread_data<F>::run() [with F = boost::_bi::bind_t<void, void (*)(int), boost::_bi::list1<boost::_bi::value<int*> > >]’|
/home/thomas/Workspace/minisniffer/main.cpp|306|  required from here|
../../../../usr/local/boost_1_54_0/boost/bind/bind.hpp|253|error: invalid conversion from ‘int*’ to ‘int’ [-fpermissive]|
../../../../usr/local/boost_1_54_0/boost/system/error_code.hpp|222|warning: ‘boost::system::posix_category’ defined but not used [-Wunused-variable]|
../../../../usr/local/boost_1_54_0/boost/system/error_code.hpp|223|warning: ‘boost::system::errno_ecat’ defined but not used [-Wunused-variable]|
../../../../usr/local/boost_1_54_0/boost/system/error_code.hpp|224|warning: ‘boost::system::native_ecat’ defined but not used [-Wunused-variable]|
||=== Build finished: 4 errors, 4 warnings ===|
```

Tbh I have no idea what's failing, but then again I'm pretty new to C++ and Boost.

The creating and binding of sockets works just fine as they have been tested already, but the thread function RecvThread() is the one that fails me.

If someone has some idea to what I'm doing wrong (could easily be a pointer (*) or address (&) that is messing everything up) I would be so thankful!!

Thanks in advance!

Comment: `RecvThread` expects an `int*` but `eth0socket` is of type `int`. Change the signature of your function

Comment: Yeah seems, so. I fixed it and now I'm getting the what I edited the post to as my output.. Which was the original question..

Comment: In your edited post `RecvThread` still expects `int *`, and `eth0socket` is stil `int`.

Comment: There. It should be fixed now due to introduction of: 

    "int eth_socket = *socket"

and due to:

    "boost::thread etc0recvthread(RecvThread, &eth0socket);". Or am I completely wrong in my use of pointers?

Comment: You aren't 'getting a bind error' at all. You're getting a ***compile error.***

Comment: Any idea what could be the problem? Am I maybe missing to "import" a boost package?

Comment: Problem fixed. There was a pointer error somewhere I think..